# 6502 Assembly Instruction not valid

Tags: assembly, 6502

I'm printing to the screen in 6502 assembly

In the monitor I wrote

```
            STA $01, y    to store the value at the pointer
```

When I press enter on this line however It says instruction not valid?

Any ideas...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The addressing mode you most likely want is *[indirect indexed](http://www.emulator101.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/6502-addressing-modes/)*

```
STA ($01), Y
```

Where eg.

```
A = '@', Y = 81,   Mem dump:

0001  00
0002  04
```

And the result would be:

```
     01234 <-- columns
    +--------
 0  | 
 1  |
 2  | @
    |
rows
```

Answer (score 2):

zp,y adressing can only be used with the X register:

```
STX $01,y
```

Comment: I am supposed to write to the screen using indirect post-indexed addressing (zero page) and read the string using absolute-indexed addressing. Isn't this done with y register?

Answer (score 1):

6502 assemblers would generally generate an absolute y-indexed instruction in this case, because zeropage y-indexed is available only for `LDX` and `STX`. Looks like your monitor assembler is not clever enough to do that.

And because your comment says about a pointer, you should probably store the pointer on page zero:

```
LDA #<screen
STA ptr
LDA #>screen
STA ptr+1
```

and then use indirect post-indexed addressing, as in:

```
STA (ptr),Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Some monitors use the number of digits you type to select between zero-page indexed and absolute indexed addressing modes.  Note that the semantics of the two modes are *not* the same.  Beyond the fact that `sta $0001,x` and `sta $0001,y` are three bytes while `sta $01,x` is two, the former two instructions will write to address $0100 when the index register is $FF, the latter will always store to a zero-page address (in this case $00).  This makes it possible to use e.g. `lda $FF,x` to fetch a byte from address (x-1), though in general the zero-page indexed mode is only available with x (not y) as an index.